# JSON No Value For Exception Also how to retrieve values if column names are entered by user

Tags: java, android, json, android-intent, android-asynctask

I have just started to develop at android platform and currently working on a prototype.

what i am doing is that i m retrieving the data from online database 
through json but the column names are provided by the user i.e. the information of which column should the data be retrieved is provided by the user 
for eg in a database three columns - OptionA,OptionB,OPtionC Are present and the name of the column whose data is to be retreived is provided by user .

This is my JSON code for sending the url-

```
public JSONArray RetreiveData(String option,String vendorname,String company,String style,String chimcompany,String shape,String size,String type,String category)
{
    // URL for getting all customers



    try {
        url = "http://piyushsharma.byethost16.com/retreivedata.php?option="+option+"&vendorname="+vendorname+"&company="+URLEncoder.encode(company,"UTF-8")+"&style="+style+"&chimcompany="+chimcompany+"&shape="+shape+"&size="+size+"&type="+type+"&category="+URLEncoder.encode(category,"UTF-8");
        Log.e("url",url);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Get HttpResponse Object from url.
    // Get HttpEntity from Http Response Object

    HttpEntity httpEntity = null;

    try
    {

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();  // Default HttpClient
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();



    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

        // Signals error in http protocol
        e.printStackTrace();

        //Log Errors Here



    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    // Convert HttpEntity into JSON Array
    JSONArray jsonArray = null;

    if (httpEntity != null) {
        try {
            String entityResponse = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

            Log.e("Entity Response  : ", entityResponse);

            jsonArray = new JSONArray(entityResponse);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return jsonArray;


}
```

This is my Json code for retreiving the data -

```
          public void SaveData(JSONArray jsonArray)
        {
         JSONObject json = null;
         sizeofarray=jsonArray.length();


          for(int i=0; i<=sizeofarray;i++){


                try {
                    json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                          Parea=json.getString("area");
                          Pbaskets=json.getString(company);
                          Prizechim=json.getString("prize");
                          Psnf=json.getString(type);
                          Ptile=json.getString(size);


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
              }  

            }  


 }
```

where the variables company,type and size are passed by the users.
Please tell me that is it possible for passing the variables instead of a string.
and then storing these values for displaying them in textview.

This is the JSon Response -

> [{"area":"29"},{"maggpie":"7890"},{"prize":"10000"},{"vintage":"6890"},{"15X10":"375"}]

This is the Exception shown -

03-16 18:28:07.638: W/System.err(3344): org.json.JSONException:

> No value for maggpie

03-16 18:28:07.648: W/System.err(3344):     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:355)
03-16 18:28:07.688: W/System.err(3344):     at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:515)
03-16 18:28:07.688: W/System.err(3344):     at com.example.projectkitchennbathroom.Estimate.SaveData(Estimate.java:107)
03-16 18:28:07.688: W/System.err(3344):     at com.example.projectkitchennbathroom.Estimate$RetreiveData.onPostExecute(Estimate.java:140)
03-16 18:28:07.708: W/System.err(3344):     at com.example.projectkitchennbathroom.Estimate$RetreiveData.onPostExecute(Estimate.java:1)
03-16 18:28:07.708: W/System.err(3344):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
03-16 18:28:07.708: W/System.err(3344):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
03-16 18:28:07.708: W/System.err(3344):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
03-16 18:28:07.708: W/System.err(3344):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-16 18:28:07.708: W/System.err(3344):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-16 18:28:07.708: W/System.err(3344):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-16 18:28:07.718: W/System.err(3344):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-16 18:28:07.718: W/System.err(3344):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-16 18:28:07.718: W/System.err(3344):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-16 18:28:07.718: W/System.err(3344):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-16 18:28:07.718: W/System.err(3344):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-16 18:28:07.718: W/System.err(3344): org.json.JSONException: No value for area

I dont know why it is showing null although the value is present?

Comment: forgot to mention here variables company,type,size are the column names input by the user. and the input provided here are company="maggpie",type="vintage" and size="15X10".

Answer (score 0):

The user input does not match what is stored in the JSON array. This is likely due to how the user input is read. You should confirm there are no hidden characters coming in with the user input.

```
System.out.println("company.length() = " + company.length());
System.out.println("company = :" + company + ":");
```

I can see nothing wrong with the code provided.

Answer (score 0):

json response is an array of json objects, not one json object,

```
[{"area":"29"},{"maggpie":"7890"},{"prize":"10000"},{"vintage":"6890"},{"15X10":"375"}]
```

if it was one Json object, it would have been in this format,

```
{"area":"29","maggpie":"7890","prize":"10000","vintage":"6890","15X10":"375"}
```

so to fix the exception, get the json array

```
JSONArray json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

JSONObject area    = json.getJSONObject(0);
JSONObject company = json.getJSONObject(1);
JSONObject prize   = json.getJSONObject(2);
JSONObject type    = json.getJSONObject(3);
JSONObject size    = json.getJSONObject(4);

//* you can get variable key key for each one, but for your example
Parea=area.getString("area");
Pbaskets=company.getString("maggpie");
Prizechim=prize.getString("prize");
Psnf=type.getString("vintage");
Ptile=size.getString("15X10");
```